# Can **0.5 return a negative number?

Tags: python, python-2.7

To find the distance, I was using **0.5 to square root. Will this ever return a  negative number?

```
def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return ((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)**0.5
```

Comment: No, that would be impossible given your function.

Comment: That said, why *aren't* you using `math.sqrt`?

Comment: No reason in particular. Would one be preferred over the other?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Depending on how a speed test is conducted, one may be convinced that raising by a half is faster. I am not saying the following should be relied upon but consider this (possibly faulty) argument: `statistics.mean(timeit.repeat('test(10, 20)', 'import math; test = lambda a, b: math.sqrt(a * a + b * b)', repeat=30)) == 0.47780620478877533` and `statistics.mean(timeit.repeat('test(10, 20)', 'import math; test = lambda a, b: (a * a + b * b) ** 0.5', repeat=30)) == 0.46188956045857404` The second is faster. A better question would be, "Why not use `math.hypot` instead?"

Comment: @NoctisSkytower I meant from a semantic perspective, rather than performance.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower, I am not using `math.hypot` because I want to be able to apply this to higher dimensions

Comment: @Carble I would like to recommend using `math.hypot` instead if possible and adjust your code as necessary. See the following performance measure conducted in a similar manner as the previous benchmarks: `statistics.mean(timeit.repeat('test(10, 20)', 'from math import hypot as test', repeat=30)) == 0.24254665303135425` There is a considerable speed increase.

Comment: @Carble For higher dimensions, consider the following implementation: `from functools import reduce; from math import hypot; distance = lambda *args: reduce(hypot, args)`

Comment: Scratch that -- one would only want to use the general implementation if speed was not an issue. Handwritten solutions appear faster than using `reduce` and `hypot` as shown above.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the function can return negative numbers.  This requires sufficiently broken input arguments.

```
class Whack(int):
    def __pow__(self, other, modulo=None):
        if other == 0.5:
            return -42
        return Whack()
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Whack()
    __add__ = __sub__
```

Demo:

```
>>> x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = Whack()
>>> distance(x1, y1, x2, y2)
-42
```

If you restrict to passing in 'normal' numbers such as python's built-in floats or integers, then the answer is no it cannot return negative numbers because they are not in the range of the mathematical operation `**0.5`.

Comment: Thank you for creating a broken number. :-)